# jquery change selected option in Select from Html string not working

Tags: jquery, select

I am getting the select from server in string format. 
below is html

```
<div id="1_datatable">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
       <div class="mr-auto p-2">
          <select class="custom-select datatable_select">
             <option selected="" value="10">10</option>
             <option value="20">20</option>
             <option value="30">30</option>
             <option value="40">40</option>
             <option value="50">50</option>
          </select>
       </div>
       <div class="p-2">
          <div class="form-group">     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Search ...">   </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

i am making a post call in which i am getting above html:

```
//select_value is getting fetched in onchange of select box present in data
    $.post(url, function( data ) {
    $(data).find('select').find('option').each(function() {
                     console.log($(this).prop('value') )  ;
                      if( $(this).prop('value') == selected_value ) {
                          $(this).prop('selected',true); 
                          }else{
                              $(this).removeAttr('selected');
                          }
                    });

               $('#content').replaceWith(data);
    })
```

but some how its i am unable to change the selected options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you did that much code. Simple to do like below:-

```
$('.custom-select').val(selected_value);
```

And the value will be automatically selected.

***A hard-coded working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var selected_value = 40;
  $('.custom-select').val(selected_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1_datatable">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
     <div class="mr-auto p-2">
        <select class="custom-select datatable_select">
           <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
           <option value="20">20</option>
           <option value="30">30</option>
           <option value="40">40</option>
           <option value="50">50</option>
        </select>
     </div>
     <div class="p-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Search ...">
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Note:- in your case it need to be***

```
$.post(url, function( data ) {
    $(data).find('select').val(selected_value);
    $('#content').replaceWith(data);
})
```

Comment: Feroz Siddiqui  glad to help you :):)

Comment: I have seen this `$('.custom-select').val(selected_value);` approach first time in my life to make specific option selected in a dropdown. Very quick and smart approach. Thanks.

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib  glad that it increased your knowledge